# How do I filter exact value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want where the color red and size 4gb just output the exact value but I am getting where size is 4 gb but color is green please help me in this regard. I am making a filter option, and my code is same so please if possible make it my code otherwise you can also suggest how can I achieve this?

```
const x = [
      {
      color: "green",
      name: "123",
      size: "4gb"
     },
    {
      color: "red",
      name: "555",
      size: "4gb"
    },
     {
      color: "green",
      name: "123",
      size: "2gb"
     },
     {
      color: "blue",
      name: "111",
      size: "2gb"
    },
    {
      color: "green",
      name: "123",
      size: "4gb"
    },
    {
      color: "red",
      name: "000",
      size: "4gb"
    }
  ]

const op = [{
  key: "color",
  item: "red"
},
{
  key: "size",
  item: "4gb"
}];

const fil = x.map(l => op.map(o => l[o.key] === o.item && l)).flat().filter(Boolean);

console.log(fil);
```

Output should be:

```
[{
  color: "red",
  name: "555",
  size: "4gb"
},{
  color: "red",
  name: "000",
  size: "4gb"
}];
```

Comment: Is the `op` array the desired filter options? I think this should be possible with a single `filter()` rather than all that mapping.

Comment: then please help

Comment: `fil = x.filter(({color, size}) => color === 'red' && size === '4gb');` It should be easy to replace the constants with `op` values.

Comment: no i need it dynamic way there many key will come

Comment: `x.filter(({ color, size }) => color === matchWithColor && size === matchWithSize);`. Instead of `matchWithColor` use `"red"` and instead of `matchWithSize` use `"4gb"`.

Answer (score 4):

You should [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

The primary operation you want to do is to `filter()` meaning the result contains less than or the same amount of values as the original array, so each item in the original array might or might not be present in the result so if you want a `1:1/0` mapping. A mapping always returns the same amount of values that are in the original array describing a `1:1` mapping, hence the name `map()`.

Additionally use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to loop over the filters. This will make sure **all/ every** (again, the name tells you what is does) filter condition is met.

```js
const x = [
  {
    color: "green",
    name: "123",
    size: "4gb",
  },
  {
    color: "red",
    name: "555",
    size: "4gb",
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    name: "123",
    size: "2gb",
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    name: "111",
    size: "2gb",
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    name: "123",
    size: "4gb",
  },
  {
    color: "red",
    name: "000",
    size: "4gb",
  },
];

const op = [
  {
    key: "color",
    item: "red",
  },
  {
    key: "size",
    item: "4gb",
  },
];

const fil = x.filter(option => op.every(({key, item}) => option[key] === item));
console.log(fil);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you its working as i was want